# Bat file not executing For loop

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008

I have the following lines in a .bat file, when they are run in a command prompt they all work, but when I run the .bat file it gets to the first for loop and then ends. I am trying to re-produce the folder structure and then only copy the .pdf files to the new location. After which I want to then delete the existing folders and files.

Thanks!

---

```
@echo ON
Pause    
cd D:\Projects\Staging    
Pause    
For /D %g in (*) DO mkdir "D:\Projects\Export\%g"    
Pause    
For /D %g in (*) DO copy "%g\*.pdf" "D:\Projects\Export\%g\"    
Pause    
For /D %g in (*) DO del "star dot star"    
@echo off   
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

in the command line you get the value of var g by typping `%g` wheras in batch file you need double % `%%g`